# excel counting + matching 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a log where I have two columns (H&G) where I have sales people's names inputted for each row. Column I lists the row as belonging to one of three categories ("name1" "name2" or "name3").

On the next sheet in the book I have tabulations for counting how many times each person's name appears, but what I'd like to do is cross reference that with how many they appear next to each of the categories.

ie I currently can tell that Steve has 6 deals. But what I'd like to know is that Steve has 4 of name1 and 1 each of name2

edit:
So I think I've not been clear on what I'm searching for: I am trying to sum the number of times a salesperson's name appears in columns F or G that also have a string in column H.

ie: Steve's name appears 13 times, but only 8 of those are on rows that have Phone

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is as in the image below, try following formula

```
=COUNTIFS($F2:$F9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)+COUNTIFS($G2:$G9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required and change range as per your data.

[image]

In above formula I am assuming you want to consider `Column F` and `column G` separately for category. In case you want both `Column H & G` to have same name for category then use

```
=COUNTIFS($F2:$F9,J2,$G2:$G9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)
```

This will give result `1` as only `Row 5` has `Steve` in both `Column F & G` matching category `Phone`.

***EDIT :*** As per @ForwardEd's comment

If you want to count row having same `Name` in both `Column F & G` only once (as in `Row 5` in image), then subtract above two formulas as

```
=COUNTIFS($F2:$F9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)+COUNTIFS($G2:$G9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)-COUNTIFS($F2:$F9,J2,$G2:$G9,J2,$H2:$H9,K2)
```

or use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($F$2:$F$9=J2)+($G$2:$G$9=J2)>0)*($H$2:$H$9=K2))
```

This will give result `3` for *Name=`Steve`* and *Category=`Phone`* considering `Rows 2,5,8` (*note :* `Row 5` has `Steve` in both `Column F & G` but will be counted once).

Comment: just another view point.  your first formula will count row 5 twice.  If the OP said in column F or G, shouldn't you use your first formula and then subtract your second formula to get the right count for an OR?

Comment: @ForwardEd - Yup, valid point, let's see what OP makes of it.

Comment: All the information is there!  Just need to connect the dots 8)  I was debating tossing in the sumproduct solution, but COUNTIFS I think is the better solution here.

Comment: I like that little trick with the >0 for the sumproduct.  Way better than the answer I was going to use which would have been equivalent to your combined countifs formula.  Nice Job!

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"steve",B1:B6,"name1")`

[image: COUNTIFS]

For referencing from multiple sheets:

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A6, "steve", Sheet2!A1:A6, "name1")`

Comment: so I'd just ad !Sheet in front to reference the previous sheet yes?

Comment: You got it! Or when making it just highlight the ranges manually, if that's easier. If you are referencing off sheet 2, for example: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A6, "steve", Sheet2!A1:A6, "name1")`

Comment: So this is what I've got but it seems to be failing:

=COUNTIFS(Deals!$F:$G,Leaderboard!C3,Deals!$H,"name1")

Deals is the page, F&G are where the names are, and C3 is where this person's name is.

Comment: `Deals!$H` isn't a range, you'll have to make that `Deals!$H:$H` for the column of H, or be more specific

Comment: Remember the structure of a COUNTIFS formula is `=COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, ...)`

Comment: awesome, that fixed it. But it's not returning due to a type error somewhere. 

=COUNTIFS(Deals!$F:$G,Leaderboard!C3,Deals!$H:$H,"Phone")

so Deals!$F:$G is criteria range 1
Leaderboard!C3 is criteria
Deals!$H:$H is criteria range 2
"Phone" is criteria 2

Comment: You may need to have your criteria in a single column.  you cant do F:G.  Do the formula once for F:F and then add the formula to itself, but change the F:F to G:G for the repeated formula that you added.  Caveat, if the persons name appears in both the F and G then it will be counted twice.  you can avoid that by subtracting you formula again where F:F is one criteria and G:G is another critera in the same sumif

Answer (score 0):

you can make n columns for each column you'd like to know and or you can make a single big column with multiple formulas.
You can use the & symbol to string together a long formula in a single cell.
Like:
="Month 1: "& countif(G1:G10,"Steve") & " " & "Month 2: "& countif(H1:H10,"Steve")
All that will output: Month 1: 4 Month 2: 2

you can string a lot of functions with the & symbol, so you can change the placeholder and stuff.

Also you can change the inquote string "Steve", for a reference so you'll just have to write this big formula once.